# How to create docker containers dynamically in Azure when message is passed in Service Bus Message queue and delete the containers when completed

Tags: c#, .net, docker, azure-container-instances

I want to dynamically create and delete docker containers in Azure for processing export request which is passed as Service Bus Message in topics

I am expecting ACI containers to be created dynamically through code and delete them when the work is done.

Comment: Create an Azure Function that listens to the Service Bus message queue for new messages.
When a new message arrives, trigger the creation of a new ACI container using the Azure SDK for container instances.
Configure the container with the necessary image and configuration to process the export request.
Monitor the state of the container using Azure Event Grid.
When the container has completed its work, trigger the Azure Function again to delete the container using the Azure SDK for container instances.
Use Azure Event Grid to receive notifications when the container is created or deleted.

Comment: https://www.pulumi.com/ai/answers/suT6jKPUBp7oityeWSJzTK/integrating-azure-service-bus-with-docker-container

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/container-instances?view=azure-python

https://www.educba.com/azure-event-grid/